# Force AutoComplete to depend on another's result

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I am trying to have two AutoComplete textboxes, with the second one being dependent on whatever value is input in the first one.

Full AutoComplete:

```
 <script>
    var stateId = 0;
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajax({
                dataType: "json",
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                url: '/api/services/app/generics/StateList',
                cache: true,
                success: function (data) {
                    var array = $.map(data.result, function (item) {
                        return {
                            label: item.stateName,
                            value: item.id
                        }
                    });
                    $("#StateName").autocomplete({
                        source: array,
                        minLength: 1,
                        change: function (event, ui) {
                            if (!ui.item) {

                                event.preventDefault();
                                $("#StateName").val("");
                            }},
                        open: function () {

                        },
                        close: function () {
                        },
                        focus: function (event, ui) {
                            return false;
                        },
                        select: function (event, ui) {

                            event.preventDefault();
                            $("#StateName").val(ui.item.label);
                                stateId = ui.item.id;
                        },
                        }
                    );
                },
                error: function (data) {

                }
            });
        });
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajax({
                dataType: "json",
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                url: '/api/services/app/generics/CityList/' + stateId,
                cache: true,
                success: function (data) {
                    var array = $.map(data.result, function (item) {
                        return {
                            label: item.cityName,
                            value: item.id
                        }
                    });
                    $("#CityName").autocomplete({
                        source: array,
                        minLength: 1,
                        change: function (event, ui) {
                            if (!ui.item) {

                                event.preventDefault();
                                $("#CityName").val("");
                            }},
                        open: function () {

                        },
                        close: function () {
                        },
                        focus: function (event, ui) {
                            return false;
                        },
                        select: function (event, ui) {

                            event.preventDefault();
                            $("#CityName").val(ui.item.label);
                        },
                        }
                    );
                },
                error: function (data) {

                }
            });
        });
</script>
```

Basically depending on the values of the first text box should the values of the second one appear. Say Florida is selected, then the names of Florida Cities should appear in the second one when someone searches. I have absolutely NO idea on how would I do this. Javascript is not my forte.Any help would be great!

EDIT: THis is my finalized, working script, in case someone is suffering as I am!

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajax({
                dataType: "json",
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                url: '/api/services/app/generics/StateList',
                cache: true,
                success: function (data) {
                    var array = $.map(data.result, function (item) {
                        return {
                            label: item.stateName,
                            value: item.id
                        }
                    });
                    $("#StateName").autocomplete({
                        source: array,
                        minLength: 1,
                        change: function (event, ui) {
                            if (!ui.item) {

                                event.preventDefault();
                                $("#StateName").val("");
                            }},
                        open: function () {

                        },
                        close: function () {
                        },
                        focus: function (event, ui) {
                            return false;
                        },
                        select: function (event, ui) {

                            event.preventDefault();
                            $("#StateName").val(ui.item.label);
                            $(function () {
                                $("#CityName").autocomplete({
                                    delay: 100,
                                    minLength: 2,
                                    cache: true,
                                    source: function (request, response) {
                                        $.post("/api/services/app/generics/GetCityByState?stateId=" + ui.item.value, function (data) {
                                            // data is an array of objects and must be transformed for autocomplete to use
                                            var array = data.error ? [] : $.map(data.result, function (m) {
                                                return {
                                                    label: m.cityName,
                                                    value: m.id
                                                };
                                            });
                                            response(array);

                                        });
                                    },
                                    focus: function (event, ui) {
                                        return false;

                                    },
                                    select: function (event, ui) {
                                        event.preventDefault();
                                        $("#CityName").val(ui.item.label);
                                    }
                                });
                            });
                        },
                        }
                    );
                },
                error: function (data) {

                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: I didn't check you code yet. But just in the question... Lies the logic mater. I would fill the fist `select` on page load, without ajax... Just like it, except if  state selection depends on some other previous value. Then, `onchange` of the state select, trigger an Ajax call to fill city names `select`.

Comment: Hi Louys, I see where you are getting at. Will try that approach!

Comment: ;) Come back with updated question if you have a new bug ;) I "favourited" the question (Will be notified of activity). ;)

Comment: Yes, that was perfect! Please make it an answer so I can mark it, I'll post my full code in case someone else has issues as well.

Comment: ;) done... Glad it helped! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thing is that you call two `$(document).ready(function () {` expecting the second to execute «after» the first... Wich is not the case.
Have to «wait» for user input.

I didn't check your code closely yet.
But just in the question... Lies the logic mater.

I would fill the first select **on page load**, without Ajax.

Just like that... Except if the state selection options depend on some other previous value.
Then, `onchange` of the state select → trigger an Ajax call to fill the city names `select`.

;)